# how can i connect to oracle database using Collectd?

Tags: oracle, collectd

i am not able to connect to oracle database and query in it using collectd.

i am unable to configure conf file for collectd that is able to connect to oracle database and query in them. I  have installed oracle client and sqlplus in order to be able to connect to oracle database. I can connect and query them normally without using collectd but using collectd i am getting no results

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected behaviour.